# What is the correct pronunciation of 'grep' and 'grub'?

Tags: grep, grub

I am a Bangladeshi. I notice that pronunciation of these vary from man to man(even teacher). [Wikipedia/grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) says 'grep' to '*g/re/p*' and grub's I didn't find.

Comment: [grub is a real word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grub).

Comment: Bangla for you -- `grep`: গ্রেপ, `grub`: গ্রাব

Comment: Grep rhymes with step.

Comment: "g/re/p" is an explanation of the *meaning* of "grep"; it has nothing to do with the pronunciation.

Answer (score 5):

The name of the `grep` utility does in fact come from the `ed` editor's `g/re/p` command sequence ("apply the print command on all lines matching the given regular expression").  `grub` gets its name from "[GRand Unified Bootloader](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/)".

Prononciation of commands and computer terms in general do vary between countries, regions, and sometimes even between groups of people working on different sites in the same country. Sometimes there is no "correct" way to pronounce a word, and sometimes the author of a piece of software [dictates the pronunciation in the documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-tex-and-latex).

As long as you're making yourself understood, you're free to pronounce `grep` and `grub` in whatever way you want.

It is common to pronounce computer terms that are "ordinary English words", like "cat", "grub", and "vim" etc., as one would ordinarily pronounce those words in English (but even then, people pronounce word differently in English too).

I'm sure that if a name of some command approximates a word in another language, the speakers of that language might want to use their own way of saying that word. I wouldn't be surprised if, for example, a Swede pronounced `grep` with a long `e`. "Grep" is [a proper Swedish word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grep#Swedish) meaning "pitchfork" (and, depending on context, it may also mean "grabbed hold of, gripped").

Answer (score 0):

There can be difference in tone. just try this..
 'grr/ /up' for  grub's this is simple..